# Using Disqus for ajax loaded Modal

Tags: angularjs, disqus

I'm having a modal that loads different content (imagine different profiles for products), and I want to add a review section for a product in the modal. I thought about making it by myself, but the HTML markup, PHP backend handling, comment reply, and image upload all that are just very complicated (and time consuming). So I decide to use Disqus. I've used Disqus before. I know it works pretty fine with stand alone pages. What I'm not sure if how it will work with ajax loaded Modal? For example, how does Disqus know the product is different and the comment section should change accordingly?

Since I'm using AngularJS framework, I checked out this nice directive: https://github.com/kirstein/angular-disqus/wiki Well, this still doesn't explain how should I let disqus know the product is different, and it needs to generate a different comment section.

Can I get any help from here?

Comment: Disqus is simple you just need to drop the integration `<script>` tag right at the bottom of the HTML layout of the modal. Pay attention that Disqus requires a unique URL for the page otherwise all the products you have will share the same comments thread!

Comment: @AhmadAlfy Yes that's actually my question, so I need to change the url each time I display a different product in the modal?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you need to set the unique [Disqus identifier](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472099-what-is-a-disqus-identifier-)

More about it [here](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables#disqus_identifier)

Example:

The following uses a unique id (maybe your product ID) as an identifier.

```
var disqus_identifier = '2583573';
```

Comment: No. if you do not provide identifier, disqus utilizes the URL. Only one thing is needed

Comment: "This is known as identifier conflict because, even though each page will have a unique Disqus identifier, the pages share the same thread ID. Identifier conflict causes each of these pages to show the same comments." - This is from their doc http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/662547-why-are-the-same-comments-showing-up-on-multiple-pages-

Comment: You do need to pass a unique URL in addition to the identifier. The 'var disqus_url' value doesn't need to match the window address, however.