# Using Disqus for ajax loaded

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, disqus

This is a tag-a-long question to this post --> [Using Disqus for ajax loaded Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071760/using-disqus-for-ajax-loaded-modal)

I am using a modal as my blog and am having the same issue where the same comments show up on each blog. However, I identified my "disqus_identifier" to be the unique ID of my blog. I used php to set the value of (id=postget) to be a unique id.  The id is not numeric, its something more like this:

"7Yq87eLm20"

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? Please help.

FYI this is Disqus "Universal Code"  (Not using WordPress, Drupal, Joomla, etc...)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    var postget = document.getElementById('postget').value;
    var disqus_shortname = 'myblogstuff'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
    var disqus_identifier = postget;

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function() {           
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Have you run a test to make sure postget is returning a unique id? ie alert it to screen, or use the console.

Comment: Yes, it is returning the proper id

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone else who browses here.

Try "**console.log(postget);**" just before the closing script tag to see what the variable is actually returning, and to make sure you see the variable return a unique value each time a post loads.

If the value in console.log does not change with the post, then the disqus js is not executing every time a post is invoked - so it is just sticking around with the value it had on first load (and showing the comments for that value).

Check to see if it is refreshing that value every time you access the modal. If not, you may need to re-invoke the disqus script each time the modal is invoked.

Re-invoking the disqus script eventually crowds the head tag with disqus scripts. On the second load of a disqus script, console.log will show a warning from disqus asking you to use their "reset" script and providing a link to [their instructions for using it](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472107-using-disqus-on-ajax-sites). The good news is, that means it's refreshing the disqus_identifier every time, so you'll have made progress if you see this.

Plugging in the "reset" script to destroy the old disqus script in the head tag and write a fresh one should finish off correctly loading disqus.